# Regular expression to match all punctuation except that inside of a URL

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I'm looking for a regular expression to select all punctuation except for that which is inside of a URL.

If I have the string:

```
This is a URL: https://test.com/ThisIsAURL !
```

And remove all matches it should become:

```
This is a URL https://test.com/ThisIsAURL
```

`gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x)` removes all punctuation including from URLs. I've tried using negative look behinds to select punctuation used after https but this was unsuccessful.

In the situation I need it for, all URLs are Twitter link-style URLs `https://t.co/`. They do not end in `.com`. Nor do they have more than one backslashed slug (`/ThisIsAURL`). However, IDEALLY, I'd like the regex to be as versatile as possible, able to perform this operation successfully on any URL.

Comment: Does it have to be `R` ? It's pretty simple in e.g. `Python`.

Comment: Hi Jan. Yes, it has to be R. That's my dilemma.

Comment: Can you define exactly what you mean by "punctuation"?

Comment: Do all URLs start with 'http' ?

Comment: Hi Lamia. All URLs start with http or https. I'm going to add to the question a bit to indicate what qualifies as a URL in this scenario.

Comment: @CAustin my punctuation I mean everything that [[:punct:]] would normally select.

Comment: In that case, you can just use the contents of character class and put them in square brackets: ```[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]```

Comment: @CAustin I am not sure what you mean or how this will help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may match and capture into Group 1 a URL-like pattern like `https?://\S*` and then match any punctuation and replace with a backreference to Group 1 to restore the URL in the resulting string:

```
x <- "This is a URL: https://test.com/ThisIsAURL !"
trimws(gsub("(https?://\\S*)|[[:punct:]]+", "\\1", x, ignore.case=TRUE))
## => [1] "This is a URL https://test.com/ThisIsAURL"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/LMiHtf).

The regex is

```
(https?://\S*)|[[:punct:]]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7lCnKJ/2).

**Details**

- `(https?://\S*)` - Group 1 (referenced to with `\1` from the replacement pattern):

  - `https?://` - `https://` or `http://`
  - `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `[[:punct:]]+` - 1+ punctuation (proper punctuation, symbols and `_`)

Comment: Thank you! Let's say that I want to substitute all of the punctuation that I AM removing with a simple whitespace (" "). I've already got sub = "\\1". What should I do?

Comment: @ChristopherCostello Then use SKIP-FAIL regex: [`trimws(gsub("https?://\\S*(*SKIP)(*F)|[[:punct:]]+", " ", x, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE))`](https://ideone.com/CWpixY). That is not called *removing*, that is *replacing*.